# Converting C++ std::string's find_*_of() methods to Java

Tags: java

When converting code from C++ to Java, what is an easy way to convert the std::string methods like `find_last_of()`, `find_last_not_of`, etc?

These C++ methods find an index of any of a set of characters.

Java's String class provides `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()`, but these find an index of a character or a string, not any of a set of characters.

For example, the code below finds the last character that is not ASCII whitespace.

```
size_t pos = myString.find_last_not_of( " \t\n\r" );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use Guava's `CharMatcher` class.

Here are tested conversions for each of the single-argument find_*_of() methods.

```
public int findFirstOf( String sequence, String str ) {
    return CharMatcher.anyOf( str ).indexIn( sequence );
}

public int findFirstNotOf( String sequence, String str ) {
    return CharMatcher.anyOf( str ).negate().indexIn( sequence );
}

public int findLastOf( String sequence, String str ) {
    return CharMatcher.anyOf( str ).lastIndexIn( sequence );
}

public int findLastNotOf( String sequence, String str ) {
    return CharMatcher.anyOf( str ).negate().lastIndexIn( sequence );
}
```

*Other answers welcomed.* [I couldn't find anything for `find_last_not_of()` in Java when searching on stackoverflow and elsewhere. And I missed CharMatcher the first time I searched through Guava for corresponding functionality. I'd like to document this easy conversion for future use.]

Answer (score 1):

If you like regex, you can give the below equivalents a shot. This might not be the most efficient method, but certainly worth considering, if you don't want to use any 3rd party library (Given that, there are no equivalent methods in String class in Java).

**P.S: -** If you are comfortable with 3rd party library, then I wouldn't suggest using regex for this task, as this might soon become difficult to extend as per requirement.

So, this is just another option :

```
public int findFirstOf( String sequence, String str ) {
    String regex = "^[^" + Pattern.quote(str) + "]*";
    int index = sequence.length() - sequence.replaceAll(regex, "").length();
    return index == sequence.length() ? -1 : index;
}

public int findFirstNotOf( String sequence, String str ) {
    String regex = "^[" + Pattern.quote(str) + "]*";
    int index = sequence.length() - sequence.replaceAll(regex, "").length();
    return index == sequence.length() ? -1 : index;
}

public int findLastOf( String sequence, String str ) {
    String regex = "[^" + Pattern.quote(str) + "]*$";
    return sequence.replaceAll(regex, "").length() - 1;
}

public int findLastNotOf( String sequence, String str ) {
    String regex = "[" + Pattern.quote(str) + "]*$";
    return sequence.replaceAll(regex, "").length() - 1;
}
```

I haven't tested above methods. You can do the test, and compare the results with the corresponding method you have got, and see if this works. Please get back, if this doesn't work.

As far as 3rd party library is concerned, you also have Apache Commons, [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class, with following methods:

- [`StringUtils#indexOfAny()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#indexOfAny%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [`StringUtils#indexOfAnyBut()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#indexOfAnyBut%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [`StringUtils#lastIndexOfAny()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#lastIndexOfAny%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Comment: +1 - And what I was initially looking for: LastIndexOfAnyBut(). (In my case, I already had Guava, and didn't want to add Apache.)

Comment: @AndyThomas. Actually, StringUtils class mentions that method at the beginning but hasn't defined that method anywhere.

Comment: @AndyThomas. I don't understand. *fail in -1 case*?

Comment: I dropped all four into my own unit tests, and they passed. It's possible I've missed something. BTW, I think could avoid the replaceAll() calls by using a Matcher directly, with its find(), start() and end() methods.

Comment: @AndyThomas. Yeah that would be a far better option, as that directly gives you the index.

Answer (score -2):

```
static int findFirstNotOf(String searchIn, String searchFor, int searchFrom) {
    boolean found;
    char c;
    int i;
    for (i = searchFrom; i < searchIn.length(); i++) {
        found = true;
        c = searchIn.charAt(i);
            System.out.printf("s='%s', idx=%d\n",c,searchFor.indexOf(c));
            if (searchFor.indexOf(c) == -1) {
                found = false;
            }
        if (!found) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

static int findLastNotOf(String searchIn, String searchFor, int searchFrom) {
    boolean found;
    char c;
    int i;
    for ( i = searchFrom; i>=0; i--) {
        found = true;
        c = searchIn.charAt(i);
            System.out.printf("s='%s', idx=%d\n",c,searchFor.indexOf(c));
            if (searchFor.indexOf(c) == -1) 
                found = false;
        if (!found)  return i;
    }
    return i;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String str =  "look for non-alphabetic characters...";

     int  found = findFirstNotOf(str,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ",0);

      if (found!=str.length()) {
        System.out.print("The first non-alphabetic character is " + str.charAt(found));
        System.out.print(" at position " + found + '\n');
      }

      found = findLastNotOf(str,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ",str.length()-1);
      if (found>=0) {
            System.out.print("The last non-alphabetic character is " + str.charAt(found));
            System.out.print(" at position " + found + '\n');
          }
      str = "Please, erase trailing white-spaces   \n";
      String whitespaces =  " \t\f\n\r";

      found = findLastNotOf(str,whitespaces,str.length()-1);
      if (found!=str.length()-1)
        str = str.substring(0,found+1);
      else
        str = "";            // str is all whitespace

     System.out.printf('['+ str +"]\n");
}
```